# Evaluating Absolute Value Expression Within Ranges

Tags: absolute-value

[image]

I am trying to evaluate an absolute value expression but I am struggling to know whether to place a (+) or a (-) on each expression when evaluating each interval. For example, is there a **quick method** that can take a second to realize whether $|4-x|$ gets a $+/-$ sign in the interval $[-3,4)$? (Without having to say $|4-x|=4-x$ if $4-x>0$ or $4>x$). I say this because on my math exams, time is constrained and I need to evaluate long absolute expression in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get to to know if |4−x| gets a +/− sign in the interval [−3,4) just **plug in the end points of your interval.**
For example out here plug in -3 and 3.99 for $x$ and since the result is **positive** in both cases 
$$|4-x|=4-x$$
If you have [5,6] as your interval then you plug in 5 and 6 for $x$ and since the result is **negative** in both cases:
$$|4-x|=x-4$$
If you have [3,6] as your interval then you plug in 3 and 6 for $x$ and since the result is **negative in one case and positive in the other** split the interval into two-[3,4] and [4,6] to get a better idea.

Comment: Without plugging numbers. Is there a way to quickly look at the **interval** and the **root** (in this case 4) and find out whether $|4-x|$ gets a +/- in the interval $[-3,4)$?

Comment: However if you have something like |(x-4)(x-3)(x-2)(x-1)| it would be good if you could plot it on the number line and then evaluate a +/-.

Comment: So for the interval [-8,3), $|x+3|$ is negative (-) in this interval. $|x+3|$ has a root of $-3$ and the interval [-8,3) is to the left of the root. Same thought process can be used for $|x+8|$ which has a root of -8. The interval [-8,3) is to the right of the root, so it gets a (+). However for $|4-x|$ the root is 4 and the interval [-8,3) is to the left of the root but the expression gets a (+). Why???

Comment: Oh sorry for that advice:I guess plugging in is the best option and graphing the function is equally good.